# How do I exit the Microsoft Teams Collaboration Application?

Tags: ms-office, microsoft-teams

I'm stuck and cannot escape. Whenever I click on the icon and select *Quit*, it does not quit.

This prevents me from logging out or shutting down the machine.[image]

Comment: For Microsoft Teams product issues/failures your tenant Admin can reach out to [Microsoft 365 Product Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online). 
For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1).

Comment: That sounds just awful!